# Apart from Tarski's study, is there any other source that has been looking at the parallelism of concepts and theorems?

Tags: lo.logic, axioms

Alfred Tarski in his next study (*Some Methodological Investigations on the definability of concepts*, TARSKI, Logic, *Semantics, Metamathematics. Papers from 1923 to 1938*. Clarendon Press, Oxford, 1956, 296-308.) describes the parallelism between concepts and theorems:

- axiom - primitive concept,
- theorem - defined concept,
- proof and its rules - definition and its rules.

I always thought this was mysterious, and I might have noticed myself.

My question would be that, apart from Tarski's study, there are other sources, research in this direction. Or *what could be the deeper reason for far-reaching parallelism?*

Comment: (Just a comment as I don’t have time for a full answer now.)  This is a huge and deep connection that’s been extensively explored informally and formally by many logicians since, between maths, computer science, and philosophy; the keyword for modern writings on it is the [Curry–Howard correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry–Howard_correspondence).  Among other authors, Per Martin-Löf has written extensively on the mathematical–philosophical aspects.